# Linear combination of vectors: expression or value.

Tags: linear-algebra

When I say "linear combination of vectors $v_1\cdots v_n$", I'm talking about the expression $a_1v_1+\cdots +a_nv_n$ or the resulting vector (value) ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the difference? They are just two ways of saying the same thing. Like 1+1 and 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can mean both.

In particular, if *in the context*, the vectors $v_1,\dots,v_n$ are specifically given, then it  means the actual value, which is thus specified by evaluation the *formal expression* of the linear combination.